# Complementing of boolean not working, with ngIf in ngx-datatable

Tags: javascript, angular, ngx-datatable

`onSelect()` is called whenever a row in ngx-datatable is selected. `isNodeSelected` for some reason is not getting complemented when the same row is selected, even though it enters that if statement. `isNodeSelected` is used with `ngIf` to display buttons. Webstorm highlights the complement  statement and says 'narrowed to true'

```
onSelect({ selected }) {
    this.isNodeSelected = true;
    if (Array.isArray(this.selected) && this.selected.length === 1) {
      if (this.selected[0].hasOwnProperty('id') && this.selected[0].id === selected[0].id) {
        this.isNodeSelected = !this.isNodeSelected;
      } else if (this.selected[0].hasOwnProperty('id') && this.selected[0].id !== selected[0].id) {
        this.selected = selected;
        this.isNodeSelected = true;
      }
    } else {
      this.selected = selected;
      this.isNodeSelected = true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: What content is this method in? There may be an issue with what `this` is referring to.

Comment: @Jacob ```this``` refers to the class surrounding it

Answer (score 1):

If this function is in your component.ts file then at least you need to replace:

```
onSelect({ selected }) {
```

with

```
onSelect(selected) {
```

as the curly brace is used to insert variables values in the template, not in the code behind.

Other than that, step through each bit with your debugger to check the values at each point.

E.g. does it enter the second if statement, if so, what is the value of selected[0].id etc.

Comment: An easy way to start debugging at a certain point is to put a `debugger;` statement in your code.